# A Calculation in Padmanabhan's Book

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry

I have seen this in Padmanabhan's book. How can I verify this:

$$d\Sigma_{mn}=\frac{1}{2!}\epsilon_{mnab}\frac{\partial(x^a,x^b)}{\partial(\theta,\varphi)}d\theta d\varphi=\epsilon_{mn\theta\varphi}r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\varphi$$

My calculation:

$$d\Sigma_{mn}=\left(\epsilon_{mn12}\frac{\partial(x^1,x^2)}{\partial(\theta,\varphi)}+\epsilon_{mn23}\frac{\partial(x^2,x^3)}{\partial(\theta,\varphi)}+\epsilon_{mn13}\frac{\partial(x^1,x^3)}{\partial(\theta,\varphi)}\right)d\theta d\varphi$$

Comment: Do you know what everything in the equation means?

Comment: @Prahar Yes. $d\Sigma_{mn}$ is surface element. $\epsilon$ is Levi-Civita tensor. And I think the fraction is Jacobian determinant.

Comment: Right. Then why don't you just calculate it and see for yourself.

Comment: @Prahar I can not! I obtained something else!

Comment: Then show your calculation and we will point out the mistake.

Comment: @Prahar Ok. I edit my question now.

Comment: @Prahar Am I on the right track?

Comment: You are. By looking at the last equality, you are interested in the $d\Sigma_{tr}$ component. How is $\Sigma_{tr}$ related to $d \Sigma_{ta}$?

Comment: @Prahar I don't know. Also I don't knwo how can I relate these $\epsilon$ to $\epsilon_{mn\theta\varphi}$!

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a few hints for you to deduce the answer. First, the $\epsilon$ symbol is defined so that
$$
\epsilon_{tr\theta\phi} = 1
$$
Thus, Padmanabhan's equation is
$$
d\Sigma_{tr} = r^2 \sin\theta d\theta d\phi
$$
This is what I wish to verify. Now,
$$
d\Sigma_{tr} = \frac{\partial x^a}{\partial r} d\Sigma_{ta} = \frac{ x^a}{r} d\Sigma_{ta} = \frac{x^1}{r} d\Sigma_{t1} + \frac{x^2}{r} d\Sigma_{t2} + \frac{x^3}{r} d\Sigma_{t3} 
$$
Then, what is $d\Sigma_{ta}$? For example
$$
d\Sigma_{t1} = \frac{1}{2!} \epsilon_{t1ab} \frac{\partial(x^a,x^b)}{\partial( \theta , \phi ) } = \frac{\partial(x^2,x^3)}{\partial( \theta , \phi ) } d\theta d\phi
$$
Similar formulas hold for the other ones. Thus,
$$
d\Sigma_{tr} = \left[ \frac{x^1}{r} \frac{\partial(x^2,x^3)}{\partial( \theta , \phi ) }   + \frac{x^2}{r} \frac{\partial(x^3,x^3)}{\partial( \theta , \phi ) }  + \frac{x^3}{r} \frac{\partial(x^1,x^2)}{\partial( \theta , \phi ) }  \right] d\theta d\phi
$$
I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. But is it the only way to get this? It seems too long! I expected that there is a short way to get this.

Comment: Nope. This is it. You're studying GR my friend, get ready for some incredibly long calculations!

Comment: @Praher I know it. But what should I do if I have just the left hand side of the equation, i.e. $\frac{1}{2!}\epsilon_{mnab}\frac{\partial(x^a,x^b)}{\partial(\theta,\varphi)} d\theta d\varphi$? You proved this because you knew what the result is.

Comment: The LHS has a particular definition. You have to know what the definition is before you can compute it. We are considering here a co-dimension 2 hypersurface and $d\Sigma_{mn}$ is the volume element on this hypersurface. In this case, the hypersurface considered was the $S^2$ given by $t=r=$constant. This told me that I should be computing $d\Sigma_{tr}$.

Comment: @Praher I see. That's correct. But I don't know why I'm not Ok with that! Because Padmanabhan calculated this and then $d\Sigma_{tr}$! That's why I thought there must be another way.